# How to access preloaded json variables

Tags: javascript, preload

I'm writing a userscript and the information I need is all available in preloaded json - but I'm not sure how to access it.

```
<script type="text/preload" charset="utf-8" data-preload-id="time_zones" data-preload-secondary-id="time_zones.json?x=true">
  {"time_zones":[{"translated_name":"American Samoa","name":"American Samoa"}]}</script>
```

What should my javascript be doing to get that json into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select that `script` element and then parse its `textContent` into a variable.

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('[data-preload-id="time_zones"]').textContent);
console.log(obj.time_zones);
```

```html
<script type="text/preload" charset="utf-8" data-preload-id="time_zones" data-preload-secondary-id="time_zones.json?x=true">
  {"time_zones":[{"translated_name":"American Samoa","name":"American Samoa"}]}
  </script>
```